# A non-separable, connected ordered topological space with no interval order isomorphic to the reals

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

Is there a non-separable, connected ordered topological space such that for each point $x$ in that space, there is no interval containing $x$ that is order isomorphic to real line?

Comment: I think that this is not possible, however I am not able to prove it. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I believe an example can be found using an *Aronszajn continuum*. A densely ordered connected linearly ordered space $X$ is an *Aronszajn continuum* if

1. $X$ is not separable,
2. $X$ is first-countable, and
3. $\overline A$ is second-countable for every countable $A \subseteq X$.

Such spaces are the Dedekind completion of a densely ordered [Aronszajn line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aronszajn_line). In particular, these can be proven to exist.

Given an Aronszajn continuum $X$ with linear ordering $\leq$, we take the quotient by the equivalence relation $$a \sim b \leftrightarrow \{ x \in X : a \leq x \leq b \}\text{ is separable.}$$ The resulting space $X/\mathord{\sim}$ is also an Aronszajn continuum, but has the added property that no non-degenerate interval is separable, which implies that no point is contained in an interval homeomorphic/order-isomorphic to the reals.

---

<sub>**Note:** It's possible that any Aronszajn continuum will satisfy the requirements. An Aronszajn line has the property that no uncountable subset is order-isomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb R$, which *might* carry over to the Dedekind completion, but I haven't been able to figure out the details.</sub>

Comment: thank you sooo much. i have another question : is there any Aronszajn continuum having the Cardinality of R ???

Comment: The Aronszajn trees have size $\aleph_1$ and so is the density of the continuum (see the Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology, chapter 6, on trees and linearly ordered sets). The Dedekind completion is then used, and I think this will have at most $2^{\aleph_1}$. The latter could be continuum, but also can be bigger. In short, not sure in ZFC.